# Complicated DCF valuation

Tags: equities, valuation, dcf

Recently I tried to do a few valuation models. I searched a lot for information on the topic, but everything I found was pretty similar simplified models.
Please recommend where I can look at more complex models for assessing the value of a company that are actually applied in practice?

I'm looking for way to make usual DCF a little more interesting, to add more details in valuation.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.10xebitda.com/hedge-fund-presentations/ - HF decks on stocks they invested in. I'd guess you can find some DCF models or 'more complex models' for valuation in some of these. HTH.